# Does openquery use distributed transactions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, distributed-transactions

Does openquery in SQL Server 2005 use distributed transactions? If so, in which cases does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can use distributed transactions if the OLE-DB provider supports it. Otherwise it tries to limit the commands to read-only operations.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177403%28v=sql.90%29.aspx